# Orient-db generate sequence

Tags: orientdb

I need an query in orientDB which will do the shift operation in data,

for Example :- i have length of 10 character data

```
PR00000010
```

so I need to do the shift operation.In that PR is fixed.I need to reduce the zero, as number goes on

increase.

for example:-

```
PR00000100, PR00001000 , PR 00010000 PR 00100000
```

the number might be random.

```
For eg:- PR000000500, PR0000000070
```

i need an query for this in Orient-db..

OR functions for this sequence to generate continuously.

Comment: You can try with a server-side javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

With this sample structure:

[image]

You can use this JavaScript function:

```
var g = orient.getGraph();
var pr = g.command("sql","select from v");
for(i=0;i<pr.length;i++){
    var v=pr[i];
    var get_pr = v.getProperty("pr");
    get_pr=get_pr.substring(2,get_pr.length);

    for(h=0;h<8;h++){

        var pr_chars = get_pr.charAt(h);  

        if(h==0 && pr_chars!=0){
            get_pr = "PR00000000";
            v.setProperty("pr",get_pr);
            g.commit();
            break;
        }

        if(pr_chars!='0'){

            get_pr = get_pr.replace("0"+pr_chars,pr_chars+"0");
            v.setProperty("pr","PR"+get_pr);
            g.commit();
            break;
        }
    }





}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what parameters i need to pass ?

Comment: there is no parameters in the function, just run it